# Pandas .any() returns one boolean per column

Tags: pandas

```
print("Data : ", df)

print("Value: ", (df < 0).any())
```

> ```
> Data :             1          2          3
> 0   0.000000        NaN        NaN
> 1  11.874342        NaN        NaN
> 2   2.236068        NaN        NaN
> 3  12.041595  11.313708        NaN
> 4   2.236068 -11.400000  12.165525
>
> Value:  1    False
> 2     True
> 3    False
> dtype: bool
> ```

I don't understand why it returns boolean for each column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the default of `any` is reduce along the index-axis, see the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html

If you specify `any(axis=None)` this *will* reduce to a scalar, in your case `True`

Comment: @IanS ditto, everyday is a schoolday

Comment: Makes Sense. Thank you